# is it possible to manipulate manage_file field on validation

Tags: forms, files

Using the form api, is it possible to manipulate the managed_file field inside the validation function. For example if the fid of the field is 15, I want to change it to 10.

It seems like it isn't because when I try the field's value disappears.